# Dealing with dd/mm/yyyy date formats using OleDb and Access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm having problems dealing with dates in my queries/SQL code. My regional settings are in the format #dd/mm/yyyy#, so when inserting a date to access database it looks like #dd/mm/yyyy# but with select query i get #mm/dd/yyyy#

```
Query = "Select EmpEndDate From Employees_Details Where EmpCode = '" & EmpCode & "';"
Objcmd = New OleDbCommand(Query, ObjConnection)
ObjSelect = Objcmd.ExecuteReader
ObjSelect.Read()
Dim EndDate As DateTime
If Convert.ToString(ObjSelect.GetValue(0)) = vbNullString Then
EndDate = DateTime.Now
Else
EndDate = ObjSelect.GetValue(0)
End If
```

Comment: I hope you have the column EmpEndDate as a DateTime and not as a string.

Comment: `#mm/dd/yyyy#` is the form dates are shown in VS - it is unambiguous, not culture dependent (it is not a bug or problem).  It is also the order/form to use when creating a Date from a literal.

Comment: It's as Date/Time @Steve

Comment: it is not a bug or problem.  The date is not changing in the DB, just how it is displayed.  Access has its own Format property for DateTime columns which may also change the way it is shown to you, but it is **not** changing the date value.  fetch a date back and display it using `.ToString` either to a control or the debug window and you will see it did not change

Comment: @Plutonix You are 100% right, I only get the different date format when i use the debug mode. When I hover the mouse over EndDate.

Comment: that is simply how VisualStudio displays Dates - the `#` is meant to indicate that since if you create a date using a literal (`myDt = #02/11/2010#`) it also must be in m/d/y order.  That way a date display always means the same thing to all developers regardless of culture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My regional settings are in the format #dd/mm/yyyy#, so when inserting a date to access database it looks like #dd/mm/yyyy#

**Edit:** Thanks to the comment below from Plutonix I realize that your question is unclear as to whether you are referring to a VB.NET `#date_literal#` or an Access SQL `#date_literal#`. My answer is in regard to date literals in Access SQL:

---

It is important to realize that the Access Database Engine ignores the Regional Settings in Windows and *always* interprets ambiguous `#xx/yy/zzzz#` date literals in Access SQL statements as `#mm/dd/yyyy#`. This can be illustrated with the following VB.NET code on a machine using the default "English (United Kingdom)" settings in Windows:

```vb
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Globalization

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine("Culture name:")
        Console.WriteLine("    {0}", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name)
        Console.WriteLine("Short date pattern:")
        Console.WriteLine("    {0}", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern)
        Using con As New OleDbConnection
            con.ConnectionString =
                    "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" &
                    "Data Source=C:\Users\Public\mdbTest.mdb;"
            con.Open()
            Using cmd As New OleDbCommand
                cmd.Connection = con
                ' try updating to November 2, 2010 as #dd/mm/yyyy#
                cmd.CommandText =
                        "UPDATE Employees_Details " &
                        "SET EmpEndDate=#02/11/2010# " &
                        "WHERE EmpCode=1"
                Console.WriteLine("UPDATE command:")
                Console.WriteLine("    {0}", cmd.CommandText)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                ' read value back and display
                cmd.CommandText =
                        "SELECT EmpEndDate " &
                        "FROM Employees_Details " &
                        "WHERE EmpCode=1"
                Dim EndDate As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
                Console.WriteLine("Retrieved date:")
                Console.WriteLine("    {0}", EndDate.ToLongDateString)
            End Using
            con.Close()
        End Using
    End Sub

End Module
```

That code produces

```
Culture name:
    en-GB
Short date pattern:
    dd/MM/yyyy
UPDATE command:
    UPDATE Employees_Details SET EmpEndDate=#02/11/2010# WHERE EmpCode=1
Retrieved date:
    11 February 2010
```

showing that `#02/11/2010#` was written to the Access database as "11 February 2010", not "2 November 2010".

A much better approach is to avoid date literals in Access SQL statements by using [parameterized queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx). If date literals *must* be used in Access SQL statements, always opt for the unambiguous `#yyyy/mm/dd#` format.

Comment: If you create a Date var using the constructor, then `yyyy,m,d` is the correct order.  Using a literal, the only order VB recognizes is `#m/d/yyyy#` the same as `InvariantCulture` format (which is what *I* meant by unambiguous) See *Format Requirements* for [Date Data Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3eaydw6e.aspx). Unlike C# which *does* use the local culture for VS var value display, VB does not so the display *always* `#m/d/yyyy#` for display and assigning a literal to a date var.

Comment: @Plutonix Thanks very much for your comment. I have updated my answer to clarify that I am talking about date literals in Access SQL.

Comment: excellent - I thought you were advising things like `Dim myDt = #2014/2/11#` which is invalid.  I didnt know that Access SQL would accept them as `#yyyy/mm/dd#`. I think *that* format rather than `InvariantCulture` makes more sense for code literals.